# Pouchdb doesn´t recognize a different user

Tags: session, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am using PouchDB 5.3 with Couchbase Sync Gateway 1.2, with the sync function. If I login using a user that has access to 2500 documents, it sync them to my device, but, if I logout and login with the other user, that has access to only 1 document, PouchDB doesn´t recognize this change, and keep data on my device.

If PouchDB is able to sync changes on both sides, should be able to recognize when the user change?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it doesn´t support this functionality.

Answer here:

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4976